Trying to identify a weird movie
I saw part of this movie or TV series in the 90's on TV. It starts out with a car driving on a snowy road and there is a wreck I think. A woman who was in the car winds up in this weird community. She ends up living or working for an older couple. In one scene the man's wife is holding the woman who works/lives with them down on the bed and the man is having sex with her, while fully clothed, to get her pregnant so he and his wife can have a kid. But it's legal for them to do so because they're in a dystopian future or something where this is allowed. Also, there's a scene where a man is to be punished for some crime and they throw him from a platform into a crowd and they literally rip the man's head off of his body. At least I think this is part of the movie.
Can anyone tell me what the name of this movie is?
